# Using aJax in joomsocial

Tags: jquery, joomla

I am using ajax in joomsocial for registering user.
I am going to send form data to server using ajax (jQuery aJax).

for it, I have written like following

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '...',
  data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
  success: function(data,status, jq){
  }
});
```

I have some problems here:

1. How do I write url for ajax in here?
2. In where do I have to implement action for this aJax
3. In which way do I have to send the result in php file for processing aJax

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this an example,

```
var data = "param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2;
jQuery.ajax ({

        type: "GET",

        url: "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&controller=productdetails&task=your_function?",

        data: data,

        success: function(data) {

            alert(data);//here you will get your result as html/xml/json

        }

     });
```

On this you have to mention a function that is "task" also the call is goes to any of the component your case joomsocial .

For sending the value from controller to view you can use this

```
   $view = $this->getView('recommend', 'html');
   $view->setLayout('mail_confirmed');//just use the variable and object on the layout page from here.
   $view->display();
```

Comment: one data variable is there you can use that for passing query strings

Comment: I have two question 1. In controller.php, how do I have to set the value that I have to send to view? 2. in view, how do I have to get the value? thanks!

Comment: should change your code for JomSocial as currently it's for VirtueMart ;)

Comment: @Lodder its just an example :)